# check if bson array include string id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

I would like to know if an array of bsons include a string id, something like this:

```
[186] pry(main)> changed = [BSON::ObjectId('5ae9972ea8abbc3c5484cd5e')] 
=> [BSON::ObjectId('5ae9972ea8abbc3c5484cd5e')]
[187] pry(main)> changed
=> [BSON::ObjectId('5ae9972ea8abbc3c5484cd5e')]
[188] pry(main)> manager_to_remove = "5ae9972ea8abbc3c5484cd5e"
=> "5ae9972ea8abbc3c5484cd5e"
[189] pry(main)> manager_to_remove
=> "5ae9972ea8abbc3c5484cd5e"
[190] pry(main)> changed.include?(manager_to_remove).inspect
=> "false"
```

I'm always getting false.

Thank you!

Comment: Try to convert it to string?

Comment: Thank you, result is this but is not same string: `[208] pry(main)> changed.to_s
=> "[BSON::ObjectId('5ae9972ea8abbc3c5484cd5e')]"` I would like to remove BSON...etc or the other side, convert string in BSON like this one!

Answer (score 1):

Converting `manager_to_remove` to `BSON::ObjectId` works:

```
require 'bson'
changed = [BSON::ObjectId('5ae9972ea8abbc3c5484cd5e')]
manager_to_remove = BSON::ObjectId("5ae9972ea8abbc3c5484cd5e")
changed.include?(manager_to_remove).inspect # => "true"
```